# Can someone help me out the correct form of been here?

Tags: verbs, british-english

I just got back from a test I am having doubt over two multiple choice questions.

> 1. They _____ playing at that time.

**Shall be** playing or **are** playing?

> 2. He _____ newspaper for living

**Has been selling** or **sold**?

I ticked *shall be playing* and *sold* respectively.

Comment: They all could be correct. The second sentence should be: He ... newspapers for a living.

Comment: Well, if it wasn't a multiple choice question I'd say "were playing" for the first. "Are playing" sounds weird to my ears with this phrasing. "Shall be playing" is also right but formal, "should be playing" would sound better in my opinion. It really goes down on what information the sentence wants to convey so it's not exactly a fair question. I'd say "are playing" is the better choice here. The second can also be right with both of them depending on the context. I'd say "has been selling" because there's no specified time nor does it suggests that it's over to make the past tense necessary.

Comment: I upvoted Chris M.'s comment. (Un)fortunately, without context, all of them could be correct. I assume that since they were just multiple choice questions, there is no context for any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately all of the answer choices are acceptable.  Without more context I could not tell you which is most appropriate in each sentence.  For example:

> We can't meet up with the students this afternoon at 2, since they shall be playing at that time.
>
> Don't schedule their haircut for Tuesday afternoon because they are (usually) playing at that time.
>
> He's retired now but when he was younger he sold newspapers for a living.
>
> Times are hard, so he has been selling newspapers for a living.